# rviz dae "file came out empty"

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rvis v 1.12.14

Can't attach the .dae file because I don't have enough "points" here.

"Could not load resource [LowRes_DexterHDIKinematic_Link1_Bottom.dae]: Collada: File came out empty. Something is wrong here."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359620/rviz-dae--%22file-came-out-empty%22/) by [James Newton](https://answers.ros.org/users/57187/james-newton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also asked here.
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1534
Turns out that mesh links can not be relative. Must be either "package:// or "file:/// (note three / ) I was just placing the CAD files in the same folder as the urdf. The error messages make NO mention of the files not being found. They say the "File came out empty" or "could not be loaded" but never mention the fact that the reason is they weren't found.

---

Originally posted by [James Newton](https://answers.ros.org/users/57187/james-newton/) with karma: 16 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0